# SQL Case Statement with syntax error

Tags: sql

Probably a basic but, I have a data set with a column named 'FME' with dates: 1/21/2013,2/21/2013,3/21/2013.....and so on) I need to create a new column and use a case statement that says:

```
if FME = '1/21/2013 then Fiscal_Month = 'Jan_13'
```

I would obviously do this 12 times for each month, but I am getting a syntax error.  Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your `CASE` statement?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You should not need a `CASE` statement for this, but rather you should use the RDBMS' date parsing functions to convert the date format between its existing string `mm/dd/yyyy` and your desired output format `Mon_yy`

Answer (score -2):

This is the syntax for a SQL case statement in SQL Server

```
SELECT column1, 
       CASE FME = '1/21/2013'
           then 'Jan_13' 
           then...
      END AS DatePrint
```

But if you are just looking to print the month/year then just format the date